# Vue.js call method from App.vue or main.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to call method from another component.
I have file Notifications.js, where I store mine notifications component like so:

```
export default {
      errorMessage(message) {
        this.$snotify.error(message, {
          timeout: 2000,
          showProgressBar: true,
          closeOnClick: true,
          pauseOnHover: true
        });
      },
};
```

And I will need them to import in mine App.vue or main.js so I can call them globaly:
My App.vue looks like so:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="body">
    <Navigation />
    <router-view />
    <vue-snotify />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navigation from "@/components/Navigation.vue";


export default {
  components: {
    Navigation,
  },

  mounted() {
    this.$store.commit("LOGIN", !!localStorage.getItem("token"));
  }
};
</script>


<style lang="scss">
  @import "./assets/styles/style.scss";
</style>
```

And this is mine app.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

import "bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
//import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap-notify.min.js";
import 'vue-snotify/styles/material.css';


import Snotify, { SnotifyPosition } from 'vue-snotify'

Vue.config.productionTip = false;


const options = {
  toast: {
    position: SnotifyPosition.rightTop
  }
}


Vue.use(Snotify, options)

new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

So somewhere in those two I will need to import Notifications.js so I could call it in Login.vue or any other vue component.
Question is how to import this functions and how to call them?
This is Login.vue where I'm calling this.$snotify.

```
<template>
<div>
          <div class="main"  v-if="canLogin">
          <img class="logo" src="../assets/logo.png">
          <form class="form" @submit="login">
            <input class="form-input" type="email" v-model="form.email" id="email" align="center" placeholder="eMail" required>
            <input class="form-input" type="password" v-model="form.password" id="password"  align="center" placeholder="Password" required>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
                     
    </div>


    <div class="main"  v-if="!canLogin">

      <span>YOU ARE BLOCKED</span>
    </div>
</div>
</template>



<script>
import User from "../apis/User";


export default {
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        email: "",
        password: ""
      },
        errors: '',
        message: '',
        canLogin: true,
    };
  },

  mounted() {
        User.canLogin().then(response => {
          this.canLogin = response.data.canLogin;
        });
  },

  methods: {

    login(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

          this.errors = '';

         if (!this.validEmail(this.form.email)) {
            this.$snotify.error('eMail not valid', {
              timeout: 2000,
              showProgressBar: true,
              closeOnClick: true,
              pauseOnHover: true
            });
          } else {


            
      User.login(this.form)
        .then(response => {
          this.$store.commit("LOGIN", true);
          localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
          this.$router.push({ name: "Dashboard" });

          this.$snotify.success(response.data.message, {
            timeout: 2000,
            showProgressBar: true,
            closeOnClick: true,
            pauseOnHover: true
          });

        })
        .catch(error => {
          if (error.response.status === 400) {
          this.errors = error.response.data.message;
          this.$snotify.error(error.response.data.message, {
            timeout: 2000,
            showProgressBar: true,
            closeOnClick: true,
            pauseOnHover: true
          });
  
          }

        if(error.response.status === 429){
          this.canLogin = false;
        }
        });
      }
    },
    validEmail: function (email) {
      var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      return re.test(email);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I need to change all notifications to call them like Notifications.errorMessage('here is message');

Comment: you would import Notifications.js where you need to use `Notifications.errorMessage` using `import` - which you already know how to use

Comment: Well yes I could do that, but is there any way to import it Globaly to mine App.vue or main.js so I could call them anywhere without calling it every time?

Comment: you mean like a [vue plugin](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) - yes, you can do that of course

Comment: Well I tried like so and It's giving me that MyPlugin is not defined, And I followed all instructions like vue plugin

Comment: yes, I see that the documentation is a little sparse - are you using vue-cli by chance? because if you do, you can use `Plugin.install` and that seems to work (I don't fully understand it myself to be honest) - I think if you first declare `const MyPlugin = {}` it would work too ... see https://learnvue.co/2020/01/how-to-make-your-first-vuejs-plugin/ for a better example